# Custom conversion rules in UnitConvert

Tags: customization, undocumented, units

I want to make [`UnitConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html) operate on custom units with special rules.

For instance, I would like to be able to convert between `"Hartrees"` (or any energy unit) and `"Wavenumbers"`. This conversion is based off of assuming we're working with light, in which case there is a straightforward conversion between the two using the speed of light and Planck's constant.

Optimally, I could do something like:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[..., "Hartrees"], "Wavenumbers"]
```

but of course Mathematica balks as the [`UnitDimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitDimensions.html) aren't actually the same.

How can I do this? I know it won't be easy, but it at least ought to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a while spelunking and came up with a solution. We can basically just dig through what `UnitConvert` is doing and although there are many pitfalls, some of which I probably have not avoided, I do have *a* solution.

Here goes. First, the most fundamental step is a function to register a new unit rule. There are many symbols involved here, so I'll post the code first then dissect it:

```
addUnitConvertRule[key_ -> Quantity[val_, unit_]] :=
 With[
  {
   customKey = Symbol["CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`" <> key]
   },
  If[Not@KeyExistsQ[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules, 
     key],
   AppendTo[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules, 
    key -> customKey]
   ];
  CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q[customKey] = True;
  With[{uc = UnitConvert[unit]},
   With[{uval =
      val*QuantityMagnitude[uc]*QuantityUnit[uc] /. {
         s_String :> 
          Lookup[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules, s]
         } //. u_Symbol?CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q :>
        Replace[
         CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup[u, 
          "FundamentalUnitValue"],
         _CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup :> u
         ]
     },
    CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup[customKey, 
      "FundamentalUnitValue"] =
     uval;
    CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF0[customKey] =
     Evaluate[#*uval /. 
        s_Symbol?CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q :> 
         1] &;
    CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF1[customKey] =
     Evaluate[#/uval /. 
         s_Symbol?CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q :> 
          1]*# &
    ]
   ];
  CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup[customKey, 
    "UnitDimensions"] =
   With[{uc = UnitDimensions[unit]},
    Apply[Times, Power @@@ uc] /. 
     s_String :> Symbol["CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`" <> s]
    ];
  ]
```

Basically all unit conversions are registered on a number of different symbols as `DownValues`. The core is `` CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup `` which stores the most important data, but for finding this symbol we need to register it on `` QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules `` and for some internal registration stuff we need to set a rule on `` CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q ``.

Next we register the core conversion on `` CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup `` via the `"FundamentalUnitValue"` subproperty. This must reduce down to other more basic unit symbols (in general it reduces down to SI units it seems).

Some conversions are "fast-tracked" it appears, and for that we need to register the fast tracked multiplicative conversion on `` CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF0 `` and `` CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF1 ``. Why we need both I don't know, but experimentally it seems I need it.

Finally, we set the `"UnitDimensions"` on `UnitLookup` as well for compatibility determination.

Now, we probably don't always want our rules to overwrite built-in stuff, so we'll define a function that makes sure that rules are cleared afterwards:

```
copyFromLink[link_, 
   expr_] :=
  ((*For fast copies of mutable expressions*)

   LinkWrite[link, expr];
   LinkRead[link]
   );
copyFromLink[link_][expr_] :=
  copyFromLink[link, expr];

withCustomConvertRules[
   expr_,
   rules : {
     (_ -> _Quantity) ..
     },
   useCache : True | False : False
   ] :=
  With[{ll = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback]},
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    None,
    Block[
     {
      QuantityUnits`Private`$CompatibleUnitQCache =
       If[useCache,
        copyFromLink[ll]@ 
         QuantityUnits`Private`$CompatibleUnitQCache,
        System`Utilities`HashTable[]
        ],
      QuantityUnits`Private`$KnownUnitQCache =
       If[useCache,
        copyFromLink[ll]@QuantityUnits`Private`$KnownUnitQCache,
        System`Utilities`HashTable[]
        ],
      QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitDimensionsCache =
       If[useCache,
        copyFromLink[ll]@QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitDimensionsCache,
        System`Utilities`HashTable[]
        ],
       QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules =
       QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules
      },
     Internal`InheritedBlock[
      {
       CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`UnitLookup,
       CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`KnownUnit0Q,
       CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF0,
       CalculateUnits`UnitTable`CUF1
       },
      addUnitConvertRule /@ rules;
      expr
      ]
     ],
    LinkClose[ll];
    ]
   ];
withCustomConvertRules~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

Note that I have a parameter in there that specified whether we use the cached values or not. Using the caches is faster (and to make sure they don't get mutated I add that `copyFromLink` function), but that can lead to unexpected surprises if there is a cached value that we're trying to overwrite, so by default I reinitialize them as new empty hash tables.

Now we can check if this works:

```
withCustomConvertRules[
 {
  UnitConvert[QuantityArray[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}], "Dogs"], 
   "Hartrees"],
  UnitConvert[Quantity[-76.1, "Hartrees"/"Seconds"], 
   "EnergyWavenumber"*"Megahertz"]
  },
 {
  "Dogs" -> Quantity[\[Pi], "Hartrees"],
  "EnergyWavenumber" -> 
   Quantity[
    1.98644585714892864895281898824816039`7.6813769430313075*^-23, 
    "Joules"]
  }
 ]

{StructuredArray[QuantityArray, {3, 2}, 
StructuredArray`StructuredData[
  QuantityArray, {{-2.687447536766794, 
   2.032843871270052}, {-2.5325772236678157`, -1.141664370726879}, {
   2.8417903071482153`, -0.966862479353852}}, "Hartrees", {{1}, {
   2}}]], Quantity[-16.702, "EnergyWavenumber" "Megahertz"]}
```

And it certainly appears as if it did. I may have missed some subtleties here, but this will get you started.

If you want your rules to stick around permanently, just use `addUnitConvertRule`

#### Extension

Here's an extension useful for all the chemists out there. First I'll use part of a dataset of conversions that I had laying around for some of my stuff.

```
$chemUnitsMap =
  <|"JoulesToWavenumbersMagnitude" :> 
    QuantityMagnitude[
     UnitConvert[
      Quantity[1, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant" "SpeedOfLight")], 
      "Wavenumbers"]], 
   "JoulesToWavenumbersUnits" :> 
    Quantity[1, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant" "SpeedOfLight")], 
   "JoulesToWavenumbers" :> 
    UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant" "SpeedOfLight")], 
     "Wavenumbers"], 
   "JoulesToMegahertzMagnitude" :> 
    QuantityMagnitude[
     UnitConvert[Quantity[1, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant")], 
      "Megahertz"]], 
   "JoulesToMegahertzUnit" :> 
    Quantity[1/1000, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant")], 
   "JoulesToMegahertz" :> 
    UnitConvert[Quantity[1, ("Joules")/("PlanckConstant")], 
     "Megahertz"], 
   "InertialConstant" :> 
    UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1/(8 \[Pi]^2), ("PlanckConstant")/(
      "AtomicMassUnit" ("Angstroms")^2)], "Megahertz"]|>;
```

This could be cleaner if I just used some conversion mapping, but this is good enough. Next I'll define a function that will extract these, but put the prefix `"Chem"` before each custom unit:

```
getChemUnitsMap[] :=
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@
  KeyValueMap[
   If[StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ "To" ~~ __ ~~ "Magnitude"],
     With[
      {
       bt =
        Flatten@
         StringCases[#, 
          base__ ~~ "To" ~~ targ__ ~~ "Magnitude" :> {base, targ}]
       },
      "Chem" <> bt[[2]] -> Quantity[1/#2, bt[[1]]]
      ],
     Nothing
     ] &,
   $chemUnitsMap
   ]
```

Then a function that extracts these `"Chem"` units, replaces the target units with their custom names, applies the conversion, then reverts this:

```
withChemUnits[expr_] :=
 With[{cm = getChemUnitsMap[]},
  withCustomConvertRules[
    ReleaseHold[
     Hold[expr] /.
      Thread[StringTrim[Keys[cm], "Chem"] -> Keys[cm]]
     ],
    cm
    ] // ReplaceAll[
     # /. Thread[Keys[cm] -> StringTrim[Keys[cm], "Chem"]],
     HoldPattern@StructuredArray[QuantityArray, dim_, data_] :>
      StructuredArray[QuantityArray, dim, 
       ReplacePart[data,
        3 -> (data[[3]] /. 
           Thread[Keys[cm] -> StringTrim[Keys[cm], "Chem"]])
        ]
       ]
     ] &
  ]
withChemUnits~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

Finally we make a little utility function and check that it works:

```
chemUnitConvert[a_, targ_] :=
 With[{res =
    Quiet[
     Check[
      UnitConvert[a, targ], 
      withChemUnits@UnitConvert[a, targ], 
      Quantity::compat
      ],
     Quantity::compat  
     ]
   },
  res /; Head[res] =!= UnitConvert
  ]
chemUnitConvert[a_List, targ_] :=
  chemUnitConvert[#, targ] & /@ a;

chemUnitConvert[
 QuantityArray[RandomReal[{}, {3, 2}], "Hartrees"], "Wavenumbers"]

StructuredArray[QuantityArray, {3, 2}, 
StructuredArray`StructuredData[
 QuantityArray, {{189634.50413450395`, 5975.770140545627}, {
  156145.9752769196, 193341.39616016933`}, {206581.95882060917`, 
  100386.34314265262`}}, "Wavenumbers", {{1}, {2}}]]
```