# Extending Dimensional Analysis?

Tags: units

Is there some way to extend Mathematica's dimensional analysis?  For example, I'd like to be able to provide it with [dimensional equations like energy=mass with units scalings like c^2](https://www.quora.com/Could-Einsteins-famous-mass-energy-equivalence-equation-have-been-derived-earlier-using-dimensional-analysis) and have it extend the possible interpretations in terms of target dimensions and/or units.

Although my question is more general, the aforementioned case is supported by `DimensionalCombinations` if you provide the additional parameter `IncludeQuantities -> "PhysicalConstants"` with this example:

```
DimensionalCombinations[
       { QuantityVariable["E", "Energy" ]},
       QuantityVariable["m", "Mass"],
     IncludeQuantities -> "PhysicalConstants",
     GeneratedParameters -> None]
```

which produces these possible interpretations:
[image]

PS:  I'm aware of [this answer providing a kludge to extend units conversions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183735/custom-conversion-rules-in-unitconvert) but it isn't clear this will also extend the function of, for example, `DimensionalCombinations` and, in any event, I would hope for something that isn't a kludge.  (And in any event, the code in that answer doesn't work on [my cloud notebook copy](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jabowery/Published/%20customUnitsConvert.nb).  It produces an error upon executing the test.)

Comment: It isn't clear what you are looking for (also I don't see the connection to the post you linked to).  Can you provide an example input that you would like to work but does not?

Comment: I had the wrong link.  Corrected.

Comment: BTW, there is a strong preference on SE for questions to be self-contained and not to depend on potentially volatile links to essential code. Folks seem okay with posting code to a permanent service like pastebin.com, if the code won't fit in a question.

Comment: The code in that linked post is a **horrible** kludge because it tries to redefine internal functions that are *bound to change* - I would be very surprised if it still works after these years.  Instead one should define their own function `GeneralizedUnitConvert[....]` which defaults to the usual `UnitConvert` when it has no special rules for the given inputs.

Comment: Maybe these questions are related: [Specify set of base units to use in UnitConvert](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191493/26598), [Getting useful units for combinations of physical constants like on WolframAlpha?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211817/26598)